# how to create a new file and give it's download button in html

Tags: javascript, html

i created a copy for a section of my HTML code now what I want is to give download button to download same piece of code in HTML form which copy button I coping but I have no idea and idea and suggestion will be helpful because I still learning js

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);
  dummy.value = text;
  dummy.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
function copyEvent() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("copy").innerHTML;
  
  elem = elem.replace(/\n/g, "")
  .replace(/[\t ]+\</g, "<")
  .replace( /(<([hr]+)>)/ig, '')
  
  copyToClipboard(elem);
}
const addClickHandlers = (ids) => {
  ids.forEach(({ id, icon, text }) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.addEventListener("click", function handleClick() {
      element.innerHTML = `<iconify-icon icon="${icon}"></iconify-icon> ${text}`;
    });
  });
};

addClickHandlers([
  { id: "copy_btn", icon: "akar-icons:copy", text: "Code Copied" },
  { id: "down_btn", icon: "ri:file-download-line", text: "Downloading" },
]);
```

```html
<p align="right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="down_btn"><iconify-icon icon="ri:file-download-line"></iconify-icon> Download code</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark"   onclick="copyEvent();" id="copy_btn"><iconify-icon icon="akar-icons:copy"></iconify-icon> Copy Code </button></p>
          <div id="copy">
          
         <h1> hello my name is shreyash</h1>
         <p> a computer sicence student<P>
         
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your html down btn

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="downEvent()" id="down_btn"><iconify-icon icon="ri:file-download-line"></iconify-icon> Download code</button>
```

and in js

```
function downEvent() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("copy").innerHTML;

  elem = elem.replace(/\n/g, "")
  .replace(/[\t ]+\</g, "<")
  .replace( /(<([hr]+)>)/ig, '')

  var file = new File(["\ufeff"+elem], 'readme.md', {type: "text/plain:charset=UTF-8"});

  url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

  //create a hidden link and set the href and click it
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.style = "display: none";
  a.href = url;
  a.download = file.name;
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to download a HTML file -

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: i don't see a way by it is connected to my down_btn and file storing only copy id div HTML so I don't understand will you please explain or elaborate it more

Comment: as you can see i am able to copy only the code of only copy id div now I also want to give to button to download copy id div instead of copying

Comment: Well, I made you a download function and was expecting you to run it according to your needs. You just need to call the function on the button click with File's name as the first parameter and the text in the file as the second parameter.